# Categorize numbers of a list into different sets and count the occurences

Tags: python, set

I have a list of numbers, let's say `A = [9,10,16,19]`.

I have four sets `{8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13}, {14, 15, 16}, {17, 18, 19, 20}`.

For each element in list `A`, categorize the element into the given sets and count the occurences corresponding to each set.

Considering the example I gave the output should be `[2,0,1,1]`.

What is the best way to do this??

Comment: What's the output like? How far have you tried solving it?

Comment: You mean you have for sets: `{8,9,10} , {11,12,13} ,{14,15,16}, {17,18,19,20}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the `set.intersection()` method of [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to do this:

```
# Sets are generated with curly brackets
# or the set() constructor
mysets = [{8,9,10} , {11,12,13} , {14,15,16}, {17,18,19,20}]

# A is a list, which is a very different datatype
# For this problem here, it wouldn't make a difference if A
# were a set as well
A =  [9,10,16,19]

[len(s.intersection(A)) for s in mysets]
>> [2, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: ya if they're actually sets and not lists, this is what you want

Answer (score 2):

```
s0,s1,s2,s3 = [8,9,10] , [11,12,13] ,[14,15,16], [17,18,19,20]
sets = [s0,s1,s2,s3] #(these aren't sets, but ok) 
A= [9,12,16,19]

numbers = []
for s in sets:
    n = sum(1 for x in s if x in A)
    numbers.append(n)    

# numbers[i] is the number of shared elements between A and sets[i]
# you should consider extension to duplicate elements. 
# as written this may not give you the result you want on duplicate elements
```

The same thing as a one liner would read

```
numbers = [sum(1 for x in s if x in A) for s in sets]
```

Consider what you want to do with duplicate elements carefully. You may need to modify this